# Simple swapping code not working in swift

Tags: ios, swift, multidimensional-array

I am trying to take transpose of a 2d array in swift. But I don't know why the swapping is not happening.

The array remains the same after taking transpose. I am working with the following code:

```
var array_4x4 = [[Int]](count: 4, repeatedValue: [Int](count: 4, repeatedValue: 4))

for i in 0..<4
{
    for j in 0..<4
    {
        let temp = Int(arc4random_uniform((100 + 1)) - 1) + 1
        array_4x4[i][j] = temp
    }
}

for i in 0..<4
{
    for j in 0..<4    // code in this loop is not working
    {
        let temp = array_4x4[i][j]

        array_4x4[i][j] = array_4x4[j][i]

        array_4x4[j][i] = temp
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your nested loop runs over all possible array indices `(i, j)`, which means that
each array element is swapped with the transposed element *twice*.

For example, when `i=1` and `j=2`, the `(1, 2)` and the `(2, 1)` array elements are swapped.
Later, when `i=2` and `j=1`, these elements are swapped back.

As a consequence, the matrix is identical to the original matrix in the end.

The *solution* is to iterate only over `(i, j)` pairs with `i < j`,
i.e. swap only the elements above the diagonal with their
counterpart below the diagonal:

```
for i in 0..<4 {
    for j in (i + 1)..<4 {
        let temp = array_4x4[i][j]
        array_4x4[i][j] = array_4x4[j][i]
        array_4x4[j][i] = temp
    }
}
```

Note that the Swift standard library already has a function to
exchange two values:

```
for i in 0..<4 {
    for j in (i + 1)..<4 {
        swap(&array_4x4[i][j], &array_4x4[j][i])
    }
}
```

And just for the sake of completeness:
an alternative solution would be to compute the transposed matrix as
a value, and assign it to the same (or a different) variable:

```
array_4x4 = (0..<4).map { i in (0..<4).map { j in array_4x4[j][i] } }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped.